# Which to use StoreModule.forRoot or StoreModule.forFeature?

Tags: angular, ngrx

I was reading about and they said that .forRoot merges all the reducers, and when manipulating the state in this way you are manipulating all the reducers at once.

Soon .forFeature allows you to manipulate each reducer as if it had a state for each one.

And I would like to know the following:

1) Is this true?

2) How to use `.forFeature()` with multiple reducers?

**I'm getting the following error:**

```
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[StoreFeatureModule -> ReducerManager -> ReducerManager -> ReducerManager]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for ReducerManager!
```

**MODULE**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

import { environment } from 'environments/environment';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { EffectsModule } from '@ngrx/effects';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { STORE_REDUCERS, STORE_EFFECTS } from './store';

import { AppComponentModule } from '@app/components/app-component.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppComponentModule,
        HttpClientModule,
        StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({ maxAge: 25, logOnly: !environment.production }),
        StoreModule.forFeature('people', STORE_REDUCERS),
        EffectsModule.forFeature(STORE_EFFECTS),
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**PEOPLE SELECTOR**

```
import { createFeatureSelector, createSelector } from '@ngrx/store';
import { State, adapter } from './people.reducer';

const featureSelector = createFeatureSelector<State>('people');

export const { selectIds, selectEntities, selectAll, selectTotal } = adapter.getSelectors(featureSelector);

export const getLoading = createSelector(featureSelector, ({ loading }) => loading);
export const getError = createSelector(featureSelector, ({ error }) => error);
export const getMain = createSelector(selectAll, (peoples) => peoples.filter((people) => people.isMain)[0]);
```

**STORE INDEX:**

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import * as fromPeopleReducer from './people/people.reducer';
import * as fromPeopleEffects from './people/people.effects';

export interface StoreState {
    people: fromPeopleReducer.State;
}

export const STORE_REDUCERS: ActionReducerMap<StoreState> = {
    people: fromPeopleReducer.reducer,
};

export const STORE_EFFECTS: any[] = [fromPeopleEffects.Effects];
```

Comment: You need at least a forRoot. Simple rule: app.module -> forRoot, feature module -> forFeature

Comment: You must have at least one `forRoot` before have any `forFeature`. It's just like the router: use `forFeature` in your feature modules.

Comment: No shortage of docs on the subject: https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#registering-root-state; https://ngrx.io/guide/store/reducers#register-feature-state

Answer (score 11):

`.forFeature` isn't a replacement for `.forRoot`, it's a way how to inject reducers and effects into the global store from lazy loaded modules or from imported libraries.

in the `AppModule` or in your root module you have to have at least

```js
imports: [
  StoreModule.forRoot({}),
  EffectsModule.forRoot([]),
],
```

and then in any other imported module you can add something like

```js
imports: [
  StoreModule.forFeature('addresses', reducers.addresses),
  StoreModule.forFeature('companies', reducers.companies),
  StoreModule.forFeature('users', reducers.users),
  EffectsModule.forFeature([EntityEffects]),
],
```

It means that `addresses`, `companies`, `users` features will be added to the global store. if you do it in several modules it still will use the same feature name, it doesn't create a store context per module. Reducers will be receiving all available actions in the app and effects too.

I would recommend to use `.forFeature` if you write a package with a library for `ngrx` or if its reducer / effect is useless without this module and its components.